# Is it possible to downgrade the Kernel version of Ubuntu 21.04 for Raspberry pi 4?

Tags: kernel, raspberrypi, 21.04

I'm working on Raspberry pi 4 under Ubuntu 21.04 with [Arducam Stereo Camera](https://www.arducam.com/docs/pi/ov2311/stereo/#start-connecting).

I can't install the camera driver because the driver does not support the kernel version of Ubuntu 21.04 (`5.11.0-1007-raspi`)

The camera driver supports only those versions:

```
4.19.113-v7+
4.19.118
4.19.118-v7+
4.19.118-v7l+
5.4.42-v7+
5.4.51+
5.4.51-v7+
5.4.51-v7l+
```

How can I downgrade or change the Kernel version of Ubuntu to be compatible with the Kernel version of the camera driver?
I already tried to find those Kernel versions on [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) to install it manually, but I couldn't find the supported versions by the camera driver

Comment: why "downgrade"? why no set the default in grub?

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu and raspberry pi. So, do you mean that I can have two versions of Kernel at the same time and then choose which version I'll use ?

Answer (score 0):

To install a specific kernel you can run this command

sudo rpi-update 56f62dee2a2385fe030724f7b39344fbc8c8d7ab

with the hash of the kernel that you want to install from the rpi-update git repository.

It might be better to find the release of Raspbian that had the kernel you need and install that as just downgrading the kernel seems like it would go badly.

Comment: What does it do?? Please explain.